# How to install mac-like global menu feature in Fedora 23 XFCE spin?

Tags: fedora, xfce

Having spent quite a time using XUbuntu I have got a little bit addicted to its Mac-like global menu. How do I install it in Fedora? I have tried looking through the list of packages with names starting with "xfce" but couldn't find any that I'd be able to suspect to contain what I am looking for.

I don't mean the dock. I mean the active application window menu (that one with "File", "Edit", "View", etc...) to be displayed on the top of the screen rather than on the top (inside of) the application window.

[image]

Comment: Screenshot is showing Unity interface in Ubuntu, so the global menu is originally *not* part of Xfce packages or Xubuntu. In Ubuntu, there is global menu plugin for Xfce via PPA. In Fedora, try search using keywords such as "global menu" or "top menu" instead.